# While in texture paint, make uv map edges visible (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, uv, image

i'd like to see the uv map while texture-painting. But the uv map in the uv editor shows only if the 3d view is in edit mode. I've seen in a tutorial that the map can also be visible in texture paint mode, how can i do this?

regards,
  Toast

Comment: There is an option to display all uv's in the image editor while in edit mode (normally it is only selected verts) but I'm pretty sure that it doesn't apply to texture painting. Which tutorial?

Comment: Yes, i know this option. See the accepted answer, it just shows faint lines, i think those lines can be helpful for orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch back to BI then select texture paint, then you can go back to cycles to paint and the outlines should stay. I think it is a bug because it turns off sometimes until you switch back and forth again.

[image: test]

Comment: Thanks. Looks indeed like a bug. At least there is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has been added in 2.71, but I don't see it in the release notes.

[image]