# Hide the UV layout while in Texture Paint Mode?

Tags: interface, workflow, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

Is there a way to hide the UV layout while in Texture Paint Mode?

I understand the logic behind being able to see the texture you're painting on (and its UV layout), but sometimes I want to look at a *reference image* while I paint on my texture image. Having a bunch of lines covering the reference image is distracting.

<sub>[Here is a related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/), but I want to do the *opposite*.</sub>

[image]

If the mesh object is selected in Object Mode it is still possible to view the reference image without the UV layout over it. But upon switching to Texture Paint Mode, the UV/Image Editor switches back to the texture image and even after re-selecting the reference image the UV layout lines remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just uncheck this option in the view menu:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you! I need to read menus more carefully...

Answer (score 1):

I have had the luck to find myself using a 3d view window that is unchecked for "Use scene's active camera and layers" with an Image Empty in front view. I then can change the image associated with the empty and still paint in the other 3d view, with none of the mesh UVs in my way.

[image]